# Find a vector which is perpendicular to both $ti+t²j−2k$ and $si+2j+s²k$.

Tags: calculus

I have to answer this question. However, I don't really know how to get started with this problem.

Thank you for reading and I am eager for your guys response

Oscar

Comment: vector product?

Comment: I thought about taking dot product and then setting it equal to zero. But I never worked with equations in this form......

Comment: Why not take the zero vector?

Comment: What do you mean by $t2j$? Perhaps $t^2j$?

Comment: Yes my bad.. It is t²J and S²k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory, the vector 'cross' product is;
$$\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} l \\ m \\ n \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} bn-cm \\ cl-an \\ am-bl \end{pmatrix}$$
So for this question,
$$\begin{pmatrix} t \\ 2t \\ -2 \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} s \\ 2 \\ 2s \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 4ts+4 \\ -2s-2ts \\ 2t-2ts \end{pmatrix}=2\begin{pmatrix} 2ts+2 \\ -s-ts \\ t-ts \end{pmatrix}$$
Not sure if that's an end in itself or if your question is part of something bigger.